# Exception creating ejb object when running client Main.java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans

This main is calling for a session-bean in the same project to send a message to a message-driven-bean in a separate project.

The other project is fully deployed and running without error.

For this project, the session-bean ejb can be deployed. The problem is when i try to run my client main code, netbeans can deploy the code but gives me (WARNING:   Exception creating ejb object : [SSSbean]) upon running it. I simply don't see why the ejb object can't be created. Any ideas?

Session Bean is below:

```
public class SSSbean implements SSSbeanRemote {

@Resource(name = "jms/Topic")
private static Topic topic;
@Resource(name = "jms/TopicConnectionFactory")
private static ConnectionFactory topicFactory;

public SSSbean () {}

@Override
public void createMessage(String messageData) throws JMSException {
    Connection topicConnection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    topicConnection = topicFactory.createConnection();
    session = topicConnection.createSession(true,0);
    topicConnection.start();
    producer = session.createProducer(topic);

    TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage();
    tm.setText(messageData);
    producer.send(tm);
}

@Override
@Remove
public void remove() {
    System.out.println("SSSBean:remove()");
}

}
```

Main is below:

```
public class Main {
    @EJB
    private static SSSbeanRemote ss;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Main client = new Main();
        client.bX();
        ss.remove();
    }

    private void bX() {
        System.out.println("Main: Client started... ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter Suggestion: ");
            String suggestion = sc.nextLine();
            try{
                ss.createMessage(suggestion);
                continue;
            } catch (JMSException j) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ j.toString());
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject an EJB within a code that is not managed by the Container.

When your execute your client code, the main() method just ignores the @EJB annotation. The only one that knows what @EJB means and how to to inject a Bean is the Container. Try to execute the client code inside a [Aplication Client Container](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html#beakw)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve EJB bean from an application which is not managed by container, you can retrieve it from the InitialContext.

Maybe that will bring you little bit closer: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI